# Selecting roads covered by point features QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, select, network

I have a layer consisting of roads and another layer of point features (traffic signs). Is there a way in QGIS to choose the area that the traffic signs cover? By this I mean the area within multiple traffic signs as is shown in the picture, black lines are roads, red dots the traffic signs and blue lines indicate the area (or rather the lines within it) I want to choose. The process shouldn't choose roads that are within the "Polygon" drawn by the points, but rather only the roads that are within the covered network.
[image]

Comment: @BERA It could be possible to manually select a point as a starting point which lies within the "inside" area.

Comment: The LF tools plugin includes a tool to make polygons from points but it needs an ordering field in the points.  I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions for this task, but unfortunately, both have some limits.

1. If you have an ordering field for your points (as John's comment mentions), you can use the processing algorithm `Points to path` to create the blue line in linestring type, then `Lines to polygons` to convert it to polygon type.
2. You can also use the `Concave hull` processing algorithms to create the blue line in polygon type. There are two of them, `alpha shapes` and `k-nearest neighbor`. Alpha shapes apparently have some issues, so I recommend k-nearest. The shortcoming of this method is that in some cases it doesn't produce a perfect fit.

After you have your boundary as a polygon, you can use multiple methods to extract the desired part of the road network:

- With `Select by location` from the toolbar, you can select the linestring features that intersect the boundary polygon. This selects the entire features.
- With `Intersection`, you can create a new linestring layer which contains only the sections of the roads that fall within the boundary polygon.
- With `Clip` and enabling `Edit features in-place` at the top of the Processing Toolbox, you can modify the original layer to the same effect. (That is, the sections outside the boundary will be removed).
- You can also leave your boundary in linestring type for method 1., or convert to that with `Polygons to lines` for method 2. Then you can use the `Split with lines` algorithm, which splits the road layer features wherever they intersect the boundary linestring, without removing anything. This algorithm also works with edit-in-place.